# SonarQube remote access blocked by firewall

Tags: tcp, configuration, windows-firewall, sonarqube-5.0

I've set-up SonarQube on my windows machine, everything works perfectly locally. I opened port 9000 (sonar's default port), but all packets - from remote machines - sent to this port are dropped, what could be the issue?

`2015-03-11 12:57:15 ALLOW TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 54747 9000 0 - 0 0 0 - - - RECEIVE
2015-03-11 13:01:50 DROP TCP remote-address server-address 58282 9000 60 S 1212141581 0 14600 - - - RECEIVE
2015-03-11 13:01:50 DROP TCP remote-address server-address 58283 9000 60 S 957699206 0 14600 - - - RECEIVE`

Sonar is set-up to listen for connection from any IP:

`TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`

*I'm able to connect remotely when I disable the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonarqube requires Java to run, and this was blocked by the firewall. All I had to do was allow the app through the firewall from **Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall** and selecting 'Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an inbound rule in your firewall for that port
Try this link : http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/
Please like the comment if you find it useful

Comment: I already created an inbound rule, but as seen from the log those packets are still being dropped.